# Windows 2008 Server ignoring LDAP request

Tags: active-directory, ldap, tcp

I'm using `Windows Server 2008 R2` and `Windows NIC` teaming.

This is an HP server. Firewall disabled.

- I have 1 application which authenticates via `LDAP` to `AD (TCP 389)`. (App is located in same VLAN)
- `LDAP` authentication from my app to `AD` is failing randomly and we have used sniffer capture to diagnose the issue.
- We found that `AD` server is not processing `AD` request coming from AD. (not respoding at TCP level, not even a TCP RST), just ignores packet.

Which debug tools can I use in Windows 2008 to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Can you ping the server on the same address?

Comment: wow "We found that AD server is not processing AD request coming from AD" thats a dozy of a statement. So it works sometimes? Like MS would tell you to do disable the nic team and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

I'd throw Microsoft's Network Monitor onto the server to watch what the server's OS itself is "seeing" coming from the network. This will tell you, at least, if the packets are even making it to the OS for processing from the NIC driver.